# Is there an API to read chrome bookmarks that does not require writing chrome plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to write an application that reads and display chrome bookmarks

I am aware of this API: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks

the problem is, you have to write a chrome plug in to gain access to this API

My question is: is there an API that provides this data without writing a chrome plug in? possibly by logging using AUTH?